# Write list to csv file vertically

Tags: python, list, csv

What could be the best way to use a list set and create or export this data to a **csv** file?

To begin with, I must highlight that my data is of type `string` so I will need a method to collect these and filter the commas and values as integer *type*.

```
signals = ['-108', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-94', '-87', '-108']

Costs = ['8325', '5175', '2698', '1754', '4767', '3652', '2417', '7527', '3698']
```

What I would like:

[image]

I'm getting the file like this:
[image]

The part of my code that write to the csv file:

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['Signals','Costs']

s = ' '.join(signals)
c = ' '.join(costs)

with open('Data_to_Csv.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Signals':s,'Costs':c})
```

Comment: " I've managed to remove the commas and the quotes from the lists" it is *very important to understand* that your lists **do not contain commas nor quotes**

Comment: `writer.writerow({'Signals':s,'Costs':c})` *creates a single row*, This is obviously not what you want

Comment: Also, it seems like you are using spreadsheet software to read your CSV. The problem is that your file is being interpreted based on however your spreadsheet software is configured to read CSVs.... in this case, it seems to not be using commas as a delimiter. Why don't you just *provide the actual CSVs you require and that you are getting?* In general, you should be providing data as text if possible, and certainly, your data shouldn't be provided as ambigous screenshots of *some other program*, in this case Excel, presumably

Comment: In any case, what you really need is just `writer = csv.writer(csvfile)`, then do `writer.writerow(fieldnames)` then `writer.writerows(zip(signals, costs))`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the length of signals and Costs is the same. If that is true, here is your problem:

```
s = ' '.join(signals)
c = ' '.join(costs)
```

What this does is created a string called s with the value being all the numbers in `signals` joined together with spaces and a string called c with the value being all the numbers in `costs`. So effectively you will have the following:

```
>>> signals = ['-108', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-94', '-87', '-108']
>>> costs = ['8325', '5175', '2698', '1754', '4767', '3652', '2417', '7527', '3698']
>>> s = ' '.join(signals)
>>> c = ' '.join(costs)
>>> print(s)
-108 -107 -107 -107 -107 -107 -94 -87 -108
>>> print(c)
8325 5175 2698 1754 4767 3652 2417 7527 3698
```

So when you call `writer.writerow({'Signals': s, 'Costs': c})`, it will just concatenate the two strings with a `','` between them. This is what you see in your resultant CSV file.

What you need to do is loop over the list and for each index in signals, get the cost and then write that into your CSV file. Something like this:

```
with open('Data_to_Csv.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for i in range(len(signals)):
        writer.writerow({'Signals':signals[i],'Costs':costs[i]})
```

This will result in a Data_to_Csv.csv file like this:

```
Signals,Costs
-108,8325
-107,5175
-107,2698
-107,1754
-107,4767
-107,3652
-94,2417
-87,7527
-108,3698
```

Note that this approach will work only if `len(signals) == len(costs)`. If that is not true, you need to handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

use `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` from `pandas` and export your current data in a **csv** file.

```
>>> import pandas 
>>> signals = ['-108', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-94', '-87', '-108']
>>> costs = ['8325', '5175', '2698', '1754', '4767', '3652', '2417', '7527', '3698']
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'Signals':signals, 'Costs':costs})
>>> df.to_csv(index=False)
'Signals,Costs\r\n-108,8325\r\n-107,5175\r\n-107,2698\r\n-107,1754\r\n-107,4767\r\n-107,3652\r\n-94,2417\r\n-87,7527\r\n-108,3698\r\n'
```

compress and write a `csv` file:

```
>>> compression_opts = dict(method='zip', archive_name='out.csv')
>>> df.to_csv(index=False, compression=compression_opts)
```

[image: csv file]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `csv`:

```py
import csv

signals = ['-108', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-107', '-94', '-87', '-108']
costs = ['8325', '5175', '2698', '1754', '4767', '3652', '2417', '7527', '3698']

with open("Data_to_Csv.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Signals", "Costs"])
    writer.writerows(zip(signals, costs))
```

But if you find [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) useful, then you could:

```py
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

Table.from_rows(
    zip(signals, costs),
    header=["Signals", "Costs"]
).into_csv("Data_to_Csv.csv")
```